# Parent Docker Containers using Docker in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, docker-in-docker

I am working on a jenkins ssh agent for my builds
I want to have docker installed so it can run and build docker images

I currently have the following in my Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o /opt/get-docker.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/get-docker.sh
RUN sh /opt/get-docker.sh
```

This works fine when I run docker with

```
docker run <image> -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Issue I'm having is when I run docker ps with in the container, it shows all my parent containers as well, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` your docker client will connect to the host's docker daemon, and so see everything that is running on the host.

To make it so your containers can run docker in a way that appears isolated from the host you should investigate [Docker-in-docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/).